# gmailr in a headless environment

Tags: r

I'm attempting to setup gmailr for use in an non-interactive, headless environment. I've tried to the following:

1. Setup and downloaded credentials via the Developers Console as per the GitHub README. use_secret_file & gmail_auth(secret_file=) within the script
2. Executing gmail_auth in an interactive session
3. cp'ing .httr-oauth from an older directory

Each time I get

```
httpuv not installed, defaulting to out-of-band authentication
Enter authorization code:
```

I'm not prompted to save anything to file, as when I run it on my desktop, and I don't give get a URL to copy-and-paste into a browser.

Running CentOS with R 3.4.1, gmailr 0.7.1

Comment: Maybe you should `install.packages("httpuv")`?

Comment: Gmailr authentication has changed. I went through the process and gave a thorough answer. It is actually fairly simple. [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507013/gmailr-without-selecting-a-pre-authorised-account-in-r/62651398#62651398) Valid in 2020 with `gmailr 1.0`