# Gmailr without selecting a pre-authorised account in R

Tags: r, gmailr

In the R script, when I try to send the email with the following codes below. It asks that the gmailr package is requesting access to your Google account. Select a pre-authorised account or enter '0' to obtain a new token. Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort.

1: email1@gmail.com

without manually entering 1 in the console, how can my R script automatically select my pre-authorised account and sent an email accordingly?

```
library(gmailr)
gm_auth_configure(path="C:/Users/Google Drive/email.json")

my_email_message <- gm_mime() %>%
  gm_to("email1@gmail.com") %>%
  gm_from("email1@gmail.com") %>%
  gm_subject("My test message") 

gm_send_message(my_email_message)
```

Comment: I think you're almost there, you have set the credentials.json file correctly. I think that the call to `gm_auth()` is missing as specified [here](https://github.com/r-lib/gmailr#setup)

Answer (score 9):

**This is the unattended / non-interactive authentication problem.**  I will try to give the rundown of the process as it worked for me.

**Update in 2023:** There have been changes over time and I have updated the answer as I needed to revisit the problem. Hopefully it wil help others who like me find the process quite confusing.

As it states in [gmailr/readme](https://gmailr.r-lib.org/articles/gmailr.html) - you download json credentials, authenticate once interactively and copy creds to wherever you like. Credentials you can get via *[python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)*, or even better - by simply creating a project on https://console.developers.google.com, adding gmail API to it, then creating OAuth credentials (*Create OAuth client ID*) **for a desktop app**. The benefit of the latter approach is you will know exactly where all components are and will be able to repeat as many times as you want. I created a separate google e-mail address just for this purpose. You will then download OAuth "client-secret" `.json` file into your project directory and call it `credentials.json` (or any other `name.json` you like). Then you will *once* authenticate interactively running below commands from Rstudio when you are in your project directory:

```
# tell google which e-mail is being used
# and where to store credentials
# I have used subdirectory `.secret` for it

options(
  gargle_oauth_email = "my-new-email@gmail.com",
  gargle_oauth_cache = ".secret"
)

gm_auth_configure(path  = ".secret/credentials.json")

# to make things simple for me I have saved the .json file in the same
# .secret subdirectory where I am asking gargle to keep the auth tokens in 
# gm_auth() is the function that will start "OAuth dance" - ie open your 
# default browser asking to approve...
```

> A few things to note that are not that obvious to a beginner (me) - `gargle` is the library that actually handles authentication. `gmailr` calls it in the background when you use `gm_auth()`.

```
gm_auth(email = "email_address_used_for_creds@gmail.com")

# then compose your e-mail and send it
```

the `gm_auth()` command with an e-mail address set allows to avoid an extra dialogue asking which account to use. This sometimes pops up on first use (e.g. if there are several e-mail tokens in your cache).

For OAuth dance a webpage will pop up with scary messages, but you will agree to all and from then on your application will be using the cache. This is `.secret` sub-directory that you just created inside your project (and you can give whatever name you wish to the cache directory) is portable - you can copy that alongside your `credentials.json` over to your new place for the application (or shiny-server). It is convenient that all is contained in your project directory.

If you are unsure and need to understand things better, you can run `gargle::gargle_oauth_sitrep()` it will show where your cache is (where `gargle` thinks it is) and what tokens are contained in there. It should show the directory you set with `options()` call.

You will need a few lines in your code after that - they should precede the command `gm_send_message(your_email_prepared_with_gm_mime)` and no more interactive authentication is needed no matter which computer you have copied your project to as long as it has `gmailr` and `gargle` libraries installed in `R` on your server:

If I understand this correctly - your `.json` file contains the OAuth *refresh token*. That allows you to get *access token* when needed. Access token is stored in Oauth cache and it is what allows you to send (or read, delete etc.) your emails *and* it has a short lifetime - about an hour. Gargle gets a new access token when needed using your refresh token. Refresh tokens expire in 6 months, if not used. If refresh token has expired you will have to do the OAuth dance - i.e. have an interactive browser there. Couldn't you schedule a cron job to send a blank e-mail to yourself once a month?

[gmailr article "Set up an OAuth client"](https://gmailr.r-lib.org/dev/articles/oauth-client.html) explains all well; my brief explanation is an encouragement to read it again, if you get stuck. You can read also gmailr reference at https://gmailr.r-lib.org/index.html - it is pretty good. But my guess is - if you have followed the process here you won't even need that.

**Note on cache:** Default `gargle` cache directory is in a hidden subdirectory of your home directory - so it is specific to *you on that computer*. (e.g. on Linux the default location is in `~/.local/share/gmailr/`.) However if you set it to be a subdirectory to your R project, the whole OAuth process becomes *portable*. Just copy your project directory were you want and the OAuth credential pair - the json file and OAuth token(s) in the cache will follow along. Access tokens are gzipped binary files that gmail creates cryptographically and deposits in the cache. One address paired to one G-project gives one token. One probably could use multiple addresses and google projects in one R project, but I so far have yet to see the need for that.

Comment: Hey @r0berts , thanks so much for this answer. Can I lean into the `gm_auth(email = TRUE, cache = ".secret")` command. It appears to be stashing the authentication dance selections. But do you know where this is cached and in what format?

Comment: Hi @M_Merciless, it is fairly OK once you read a few times. For `gm_auth` the option `email=TRUE` means look into the cache for a suitable auth token (_a gzipped binary file_). If you say `email=my.address@gmail.com` it means the same, but look for that specific email auth token. Just in case you have a few tokens there. I prefer to give a the specific address even if I use only one id / token. Lastly `cache=.secret` simply gives instruction to cache tokens in your current/project directory `.secret` subdirectory. It will be created if not exists. See also https://gmailr.r-lib.org/index.html

Comment: @r0berts This is a great answer. I read the official docs before this answer. After reading your answer, the official instructions come off as being written as an afterthought (no offense intended to Jim Hester). I think your answer should be edited into the README in some way or another (maybe as an example/tutorial). Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add the "from e-mail address" with `gm_auth(email = "email1@gmail.com")`

````
library(gmailr)
gm_auth_configure(path="C:/Users/Google Drive/email.json")
gm_auth(email = "email1@gmail.com")

my_email_message <- gm_mime() %>%
  gm_to("email1@gmail.com") %>%
  gm_from("email1@gmail.com") %>%
  gm_subject("My test message") 

gm_send_message(my_email_message)```
````